# Find servers that have a service

Tags: powershell

I've written the below script to find servers that have the "SolarWinds Agent" service.

```
$Servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and (OperatingSystem -like 'Windows Server*')  }).Name
$Service = 'SolarWinds Agent'
$Results = @()

foreach($i in $Servers){
    if(Test-Connection $i -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        if((Get-Service $Service -ComputerName $i -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).DisplayName -eq $Service)
        {$Results += $i}
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there's a better way to write the code.

Comment: is `SolarWinds Agent` the service Name or the DisplayName??

Comment: The first positional parameter for [Get-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-7.1) is `-Name`.  
You are testing if there is a service with both `Name` and `DisplayName` are equal to 'SolarWinds Agent'.. Also, you are creating the results array using `+=` concatenation, which is a bad habit as you can easily let PowerShell collect the results if you would use `$Results = foreach(...)`. And... `-Filter` should be a **string**, not a scriptblock

Comment: the name is "SolarWindsAgent64" while the display name is 'Solarwinds Agent'

Comment: @Theo, I don't follow your logic on the 2nd reply. Please write out the code for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$Servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True' -and OperatingSystem -like 'Windows Server*'").Name
$Service = 'SolarWinds Agent'
$Results = foreach ($computer in $Servers) {
    if(Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        if(Get-Service -DisplayName $Service -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { $computer }
    }
}
```

<sup>You can in fact leave out the Test-Connection if you like</sup>

Comment: why should i leave out the test-connection? because of the -ErrorAction?

Comment: @Nuisance yep, that should be enough to silently skip servers that are not responding